# Suggestion on RAID configuration

Tags: raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

We are going to setup a storage solution for our security surveillance software. We are going to buy servers from http://www.hetzner.de and we would like to deploy RAID configuration using the following combination:
RAID CARD = MegaRAID SAS 9260-4i
HARD DISKS = 4 X 3TB, Seagate Constellation ES.2 ST33000650NS

We have two different requirements for two different servers (same hardware)
A.  Write jpeg image files ranging from 30KB to 100KB at a speed of 100 files per second. At the same time we also deleting the old imagery at the same speed.
B. Write 40MB video files 1MB/sec to 3MB/sec  and we divide this throughput into 100 files at a time. At the same time we also deleting the old imagery at the same speed.

In the past we have been observing disk performance issues on RAID 5 with different hardware. I would request you to give us advice on:

1. Appropriate RAID configuration(s) that suits our two requirements separately.
2. What possible I/O thought we can get on your suggested configuration.
3. Send us I/O benchmark data you may have with similar hardware.

Hardware Specs:
CPU : Intel® Core™ i7-3930K Hexacore
RAM : 64 GB DDR3
Mother board : EX 10: Intel DX79TO
Hard disks : 4X3TB Seagate Constellation ES.2 ST33000650NS
RAID CARD : LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260-4i 
Operating System :windows 2008 (possibly 2012)

Comment: Benchmarking is something ***YOU*** need to do (it is a type of [capacity planning](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/)) -- for the rest, the duplicate link should get you going in the right direction.  If you feel this question is not a duplicate please flesh it out a bit more (tell us something about the evaluation you did and what specific questions you have) and I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using zoneminder (?)
I would (and had) placed RAID6 of 6 disks on my videoserver (22 cameras). Basically the speed of the disks is not a problem, while the security of failing is critical. RAID 6 protect you from loosing up to 2 disks... The optimization of deleting can be make trough the "options" menu in the ZM configuration menu. Just hit the option "delete files on background".

Just make sure you buy nice peace of disks (i choosed SAS drives). The differences here :
http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/CS-031831.htm

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to connect a BBU to the Raid Controller and enable write Cache. Performance wise, and especially because of your requirement running 100 congruent IOs, I would suggest SAS Drives because of significant lower AccessTime. But it also depends on your sapce requirements and allowed costs.

Raid10 writes faster as Raid5 but with 4 drives you can not have an Hot-Spare. Raid6 is the most failproof (especially with large disk) but is slower than Raid5. Still my Advice would be 4x15K SAS on Raid6, with BBU and write-cache on the Controller.

What is your backup plan, and how much HD space is required?